# Get highest value in time range every day (xts)

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset, xts, zoo

XTS object XTS1 has about three days of data in 15 minute intervals. I want to **find the maximum values registered every day between 900am and 930am, and then record such values on a vector**. As shown in the example.

I would then do the same for the minimum. The objective is to record the daily opening range for a financial instrument (daily opening range = daily max & min during a time range). To keep it simple I'm ignoring the minimum on this example.

The question is very similar if not a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615333/r-next-highest-value-in-a-time-series?rq=1). Yet the solution provided there is for finding weekly maximums in a database with daily frequency, whereas this one is for finding hourly maximums in a database with intraday frequency. More importantly, the solution provided there does not work for this case (see below).

```
library('xts')
XTS1 <- structure(c(0.2284, 0.2283, 0.2284, 0.2288, 0.2307, 0.2319, 0.2322, 0.2327, 0.2328, 0.2327, 0.2327, 0.2327, 0.2331, 0.2338, 0.2338, 0.2346, 0.2348, 0.2348, 0.236, 0.2361, 0.2362, 0.236, 0.2365, 0.2364, 0.2363, 0.236, 0.2359, 0.2364, 0.2365, 0.2363, 0.2363, 0.2362, 0.2363, 0.2364, 0.2365, 0.2365, 0.2364, 0.2364, 0.2363, 0.2363, 0.2364, 0.2363, 0.2363, 0.2363, 0.2364, 0.2364, 0.2364, 0.2364, 0.2365, 0.2365, 0.2365, 0.2365, 0.2365, 0.2366, 0.2366, 0.2365, 0.2365, 0.2364, 0.2364, 0.2364, 0.2364, 0.2363, 0.2365, 0.2365, 0.2366, 0.2365, 0.2365, 0.2364, 0.2364, 0.2368, 0.2373, 
                    0.2378, 0.2379, 0.2382, 0.2383, 0.2384, 0.2384, 0.2384, 0.2383, 0.2385, 0.2385, 0.2387, 0.2385, 0.2385, 0.2385, 0.2386, 0.2387, 0.2387, 0.24, 0.2394, 0.2396, 0.2394, 0.2398, 0.2394, 0.2396, 0.24, 0.24, 0.2401, 0.2397, 0.2399, 0.2492, 0.2398, 0.2203, 0.2104, 0.2104, 0.2404, 0.2398, 0.24, 0.2401, 0.2402, 0.2399, 0.24, 0.24, 0.2403, 0.2406, 0.2401, 0.2404, 0.2406, 0.2406, 0.2405, 0.241, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.241, 0.2405, 0.2406, 0.2405, 0.2404, 0.2404, 0.2406, 0.2408, 0.2406, 0.2406, 0.2407, 0.2407, 0.2407, 0.2408, 0.2408, 0.2408, 0.2408, 0.2408, 0.2408, 0.2408, 0.2411, 0.241, 0.241, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2412, 0.2412, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.2412, 0.2412, 0.2412, 0.2412, 0.2412, 0.2412, 0.2412, 0.2411, 0.2412, 0.2412, 0.2412, 0.2413, 0.2412, 0.2411, 0.2411, 0.241, 0.241, 0.2411, 0.2409, 0.2417, 0.2422, 0.2421, 0.2428, 0.2426, 0.2428, 0.2421, 0.2421, 0.2419, 0.2422, 0.2424, 0.2427, 0.2437, 0.2438, 0.2441, 0.2442), .Dim = c(199L, 1L), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "", class = c("xts", "zoo"), .CLASS = structure("double", class = "CLASS"), formattable = structure(list(formatter = "formatC", format = structure(list(format = "f", digits = 2), .Names = c("format", "digits")), preproc = "percent_preproc", postproc = "percent_postproc"), .Names = c("formatter", "format", "preproc", "postproc")), index = structure(c(1413981900, 1413982800, 1413983700, 1413984600, 1413985500, 1413986400, 1413987300, 1413988200, 1413989100, 1413990000, 1413990900, 1413991800, 1413992700, 1413993600, 1413994500, 1413995400, 1413996300, 1413997200, 1413998100, 1413999000, 1413999900, 1414000800, 1414001700, 1414002600, 1414003500, 1414004400, 1414005300, 1414006200, 1414007100, 1414008000, 1414009800, 1414010700, 1414011600, 1414015200, 1414016100, 1414017000, 1414017900, 1414018800, 1414019700, 1414020600, 1414021500, 1414022400, 1414023300, 1414024200, 1414025100, 1414026000, 1414026900, 1414027800, 1414028700, 1414029600, 1414030500, 1414031400, 1414032300, 1414033200, 1414034100, 1414035000, 1414035900, 1414036800, 1414037700, 1414038600, 1414039500, 1414040400, 1414041300, 1414042200, 1414043100, 1414044000, 1414044900, 1414045800, 1414046700, 1414047600, 1414048500, 1414049400, 1414050300, 1414051200, 1414052100, 1414053000, 1414053900, 1414054800, 1414055700, 1414056600, 1414057500, 1414058400, 1414059300, 1414060200, 1414061100, 1414062000, 1414062900, 1414063800, 1414064700, 1414065600, 1414066500, 1414067400, 1414068300, 1414069200, 1414070100, 1414071000, 1414071900, 1414072800, 1414073700, 1414074600, 1414075500, 1414076400, 1414077300, 1414078200, 1414079100, 1414080000, 1414080900, 1414081800, 1414082700, 1414083600, 1414084500, 1414085400, 1414086300, 1414087200, 1414088100, 1414089000, 1414089900, 1414090800, 1414091700, 1414092600, 1414093500, 1414094400, 1414096200, 1414097100, 1414098000, 1414101600, 1414102500, 1414103400, 1414104300, 1414105200, 1414106100, 1414107000, 1414107900, 1414108800, 1414109700, 1414110600, 1414111500, 1414112400, 1414113300, 1414114200, 1414115100, 1414116000, 1414116900, 1414117800, 1414118700, 1414119600, 1414120500, 1414121400, 1414122300, 1414123200, 1414124100, 1414125000, 1414125900, 1414126800, 1414127700, 1414128600, 1414129500, 1414130400, 1414131300, 1414132200, 1414133100, 1414134000, 1414134900, 1414135800, 1414136700, 1414137600, 1414138500, 1414139400, 1414140300, 1414141200, 1414142100, 1414143000, 1414143900, 1414144800, 1414145700, 1414146600, 1414147500, 1414148400, 1414149300, 1414150200, 1414151100, 1414152000, 1414152900, 1414153800, 1414154700, 1414155600, 1414156500, 1414157400, 1414158300, 1414159200, 1414160100, 1414161000, 1414161900, 1414162800, 1414163700, 1414164600, 1414165500, 1414166400, 1414167300), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")))

#DESIRED OUTPUT
                      [,1]  Max900.930am
2014-10-22 08:45:00 0.2284            NA
2014-10-22 09:00:00 0.2283        0.2283    
2014-10-22 09:15:00 0.2284        0.2284
2014-10-22 09:30:00 0.2288        0.2288
2014-10-22 09:45:00 0.2307        0.2288
2014-10-22 10:00:00 0.2319        0.2288
.....

#This records max on desired time range, but in whole database rather than for every day
max(XTS1['T09:00:00/T09:30:00'])

#This says "Error: width > 0 is not TRUE"
xxx = rollapply(data = XTS1, width = XTS1['T09:00:00/T09:30:00'], FUN = max)

#This is derived from solution by @JoshuaUlrich to the other question
#Doesn't work: records max on desired time range, in whole database rather than every day
 Max900.930am <- apply.daily(XTS1["T09:00/T09:30"], function(x) max(XTS1))
 y <- merge(XTS1, Max900.930am, fill = na.locf)

#Printout of Max900.930am, showing the problem 
                      [,1]
2014-10-22 09:30:00 0.2492
2014-10-23 09:30:00 0.2492
2014-10-24 09:30:00 0.2492
```

Comment: Don't you just want this? `apply.daily(XTS1, function(x) max(x['T09:00:00/T09:30:00']))`

Comment: Yes, thank you! Massive step in the right direction. Still off as it only starts recording the 900-930am maximum at midnight of the day after. Guess I could lag it to get around it. Will look into it later - been up for 22 hours straight. Txs again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close with this line of code:

```
Max900.930am <- apply.daily(XTS1["T09:00/T09:30"], function(x) max(XTS1))
```

But there's a crucial typo: `max(XTS1)` should be `max(x)`. This error is why you get the maximum for the entire series, not just the day.  This would have worked:

```
Max900.930am <- apply.daily(XTS1["T09:00/T09:30"], max)
```

And you can easily get both the max and the min with one call:

```
range0900.0930 <- apply.daily(XTS1["T09:00/T09:30"], range)
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution is better. More straightforward. And applicable to multiple time frames.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
 library('data.table')
 Max900.930am <- apply.daily(XTS1, function(x) max(x['T09:00:00/T09:15:00']))
 y <- merge(XTS1, Max900.930am, fill = na.locf)
 y$Max900.930am <- shift(y$Max900.930am, n=53, type=c("lead"))
```

Thanks to @jbaums for this.

Comment: Why do you need `shift`? And you need to be careful when working with `dplyr` and time series data, because `dplyr::lag` masks the `stats::lag` generic function, which prevents S3 method dispatch. That means calling `lag(XTS1)` will not work as expected if `dplyr` is loaded.

Comment: Very useful to know that about `dplyr`. Thanks. There's a mistake on my code: I used `shift` from `data.table`, not `dplyr`.

Comment: I was unable to shift an xts forward with its built in `lag` function; just realized that even though for lagging `lag(XTS1, 1)` works, for shifting forward one needs `lag(XTS1, k = -1)` ... i.e. the "k" can be omitted when lagging but not when shifting fwd. So there is no need for `data.table`.

Comment: You don't have to specify `k` when shifting forward. This works fine for me in a clean R session: `library(xts); lag(.xts(1:3,1:3),-1)`.

Comment: You are right. I had been unable to do so before, must have been something else in my code.